# Using a variable with rename command

Tags: shell-script, regular-expression, rename, command, variable

I want to use the `rename` command to remove characters on a file basename, based on characters entered (input) by the user in an interactive script.

Basically, I would like to do this:

```
read characters_to_remove_inputted_by_the_user

rename 's/$characters_to_remove_inputted_by_the_user//g' file
```

But I'm having trouble with properly inserting the variable and keep the command structure during the script execution.

Comment: I have to say that I have never used the `rename` command.  However, according to the `rename` manpage, your syntax appears to be also wrong.  The synopsis is `rename [options] expression replacement file...`

Comment: Yes probably i am not using it correctly at the first place. I will try the first answer, but thanks for your help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming -- as your own command line suggests -- [`perl`'s `rename` implementation](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man1/prename.1.html) (an example script shipped with `perl` since version 3 in 1989, and often included as a command in many OSes, sometimes as a rewrite with extensions separate from the `perl` package like [this one](http://search.cpan.org/~pederst/rename-1.9/bin/rename.PL)), sometimes called `prename` on some Linux distributions where `rename` is otherwise [the one from `util-linux`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man1/rename.ul.1.html), you can use the environment:

```
STRING=$characters_to_remove_inputted_by_the_user rename 's/\Q$ENV{STRING}\E//g' ./*
```

Above, the content of the `$characters_to_remove_inputted_by_the_user` *shell* variable is passed as the value of the `STRING` *environment* variable which `perl` retrieves with `$ENV{STRING}`.

Alternatively, you could use the `export` shell special builtin so that that shell variable be passed in the environment of every command it executes including that `rename`:

```
export characters_to_remove_inputted_by_the_user
rename 's/\Q$ENV{characters_to_remove_inputted_by_the_user}\E//g' ./*
```

The `\Q`/`\E` are to make sure `$STRING` is treated as a fixed string and not a regexp. If you want it to be treated as a regexp, that's just:

```
REGEXP=$characters_to_remove_inputted_by_the_user rename 's/$ENV{REGEXP}//g' ./*
```

Avoid things like:

```
rename "s/$characters_to_remove_inputted_by_the_user//g" ./*
```

Above the content of the shell variable is expanded by the shell before calling `rename`, so that could amount to a command injection vulnerability, as the value of the variable would be interpreted as `perl` code (think for instance of a value like `//;system("reboot");s/`).

Comment: Does not work on Fedora 25.   Error message is `rename: not enough arguments`

Comment: @fpmurphy1, you've got the wrong `rename`, the one from `util-linux`. The OP seems to be using the perl one (might be called `prename` on Fedora).

Comment: on arch, install `perl-rename`

Answer (score 1):

With [`util-linux` `rename`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man1/rename.ul.1.html):

```
$ touch myfile1
$ ll
total 0
-rw-rw-r--. 1 fpm fpm 0 Mar 25 15:30 myfile1
$ read DELCHARS
my
$ rename -- "$DELCHARS" "" myfile1
$ ll
total 0
-rw-rw-r--. 1 fpm fpm 0 Mar 25 15:30 file1
$
```

Comment: Hi there, what i want to do is to have the user entering a sequence of all the characters he wants to remove from a filename.

Comment: Have you run my example?  Are the characters to be removed contiguous or random?    Your example assumes they are contiguous.

Comment: hey @fpmurphy1 the idea was :
User input all the characters he want to remove this way :
&#"/
to remove & and # and " and /
The script use rename to go through all files basenames and remove those characters if found.
The answer below from Stéphane definitely helped and solved my issue.

Comment: @VinhFrancisGuyait.  You initially failed to specify which `rename` you were using.  I  provided answer for the more common `util-linux` version - not the Perl version.